# How to modify the default posts list in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if there is a way to modify the default post list in the wordpress admin panel.

Assume there are some users with `post manager` role and I don't want them to see all the posts. They need to see the posts from the from a specific group. Let there are 3 `Post Managers` named Alex, Byron and Chalice, and and they are assigned to Groups Alpha, Omega and Zeta respectively. Alex needs to see the posts from alpha, Byron will see the posts from Omega and so on. None of them can see posts from any other group.

I'm grouping the posts by assigning a specific meta value in them and meta query returns me all the posts under my desired group.

By default I see any `Post Manager` can see all the posts in the Wordpress admin panel.

Now I'm looking for a way to modify the default post list to the list of the posts from a specific group based on the logged in `Post Manager`.

I've tried an `action` `restrict_manage_posts` that allowed me to setup a dropdown that would filter the posts list. This requires a query before the filter. I need to filter the post list when a Post Manger clicks on the `view all posts` link in the admin panel.

Any idea from the experts?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to hook into [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and modify the `$wp_query` object.

Some references:

- [Restrict Contributors to view only their own custom post types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89233/12615)
- [Separate Media Library for each user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72370/12615)

To load the hook only in the posts listing admin page, use:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'post' !== $typenow )
        return;

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I've checked this and I've done it :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

after searching for an hour... very simple.
in the top, open  "Screen options" and type the amount you want to view.
that's it.

Comment: Actually that wasn't the case I was looking for. Default settings allow you to modify everything. All you wanted to do is change the number of the post showing. But in my case I wanted to filter the list of post based on some conditions. The accepted answer is all good. And also thank you for your comment.