# customizing WP admin dashboard search queries

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have a custom post type, and I want to customize the returned set of post when searching for posts of this post type in the admin dashboard.

I tried doing this useing the following 3 hooks:
`posts_join`, `posts_search` (& maybe `posts_fields`).

When the execution reaches the functions I added using those hooks, there is already a significant amount of SQL in the query parts that I can modify/append to and
for some reason the changes I made are causing the search results to return posts that aren't even from my custom post type...

my Q is - Are there standards for what type of changes I can/may do to them in order to not prevent collisions with other plugins? are there any standards I should follow? (e.g. always have the $search within parenthesis when I am done with my changes?

Also what would be the best way to me to view the final resulting SQL for the entire query before it executes?

Comment: For somewhere to start, the action and filter hooks you'll need are referenced in the answers to these questions: 1. [Filter custom post type based on post meta value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684147); 2. [How to modify the default posts list in wordpress admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735032)